# Density function on a hemisphere

Tags: density-function

I have a probability density function which is defined on a unit square. $D = [0,1] \times [0,1]$
$$\displaystyle \int_D p(X)dX = 1$$

$Z = f(X)$ transforms the 2d cartesian coordinates to spherical coordinates.  $q(Z)$ is a new density function which its domain is defined on a unit hemiphere surface. I use a UV-mapping. In other words.

$$f: (x,y) \to (cos(2\pi x)\sqrt{1-y^2}, sin(2\pi x)\sqrt{1-y^2}, y)$$

Is $q(Z)$ equal to $\frac{p(X)}{2\pi}$? If it is true how could I prove it?
I used this equation and it returns correct results in my code.

Edit: Jacobian of f is:
$$J_f=\begin{bmatrix}-2\pi sin(2\pi x)\sqrt{1-y^2} & 2\pi cos(2\pi x)\sqrt{1-y^2} & 0\\ \frac{-cos(2\pi x)y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}& \frac{-sin(2\pi x)y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

$$J_fJ_f^t=\begin{bmatrix}4\pi^2(1-y^2) & 0\\ 0& \frac{1}{{1-y^2}}\end{bmatrix}$$

$$det(J_fJ_f^t)=4\pi^2$$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Any probability distribution defined on a *surface* in three dimensions does not have a density.  What kind of object, then, is $q$ supposed to be?

Comment: I mean domain is defined on the surface of unit hemisphere.

Comment: Fine: but that is accomplished only through parameterization with two real parameters.  That is what your function $f$ does.  It's still unclear what "$q$" might possibly be.  There does seem to be a question about what the "Jacobian" of a map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ might be (which is what your $f$ is).